# Using a exFAT formatted disk for backups in Clonezilla

Tags: mount, clone, clonezilla, automount, exfat

I want to create a backup image of my laptop disk to a 1TB external exFAT formatted disk using Clonezilla. However, it **fails to recognize** that the disk is exFAT, and it won't mount properly.

How can I mount the drive *without* going into the CMD or Expert Mode (for ex. using TTY2), in a way that I can be **positive that no files on the drive will be harmed?**

Comment: See this thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Help/thread/c24de9ed/
They say "I just found out that exfat partitions do work with clonezilla home image save locations. The windows format did not work though. I had to use USB STORAGE FORMAT TOOL 5.0 since HP usb format does not do exfat."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finished the backup just now and can confirm that Clonezilla supports exFAT external drives as a repository for images

[image]

I used the latest alternative version of Clonezilla [20201102-groovy](https://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative), based on Ubuntu Focal 20.04

Comment: Oh cool, I guess this is due to the new Samsung exFAT driver in Linux.